# MySQL JOIN query with result in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 MySQL tables

`tbl_user`

```
user_id | user_name
1       | John
2       | Kevin
```

`tbl_admin`

```
admin_id | admin_name
1        | Bob

SELECT `tbl_user`.`user_id` as `ID`, `tbl_user`.`user_name` as `NAME`, 
`tbl_admin`.`admin_id` as `ID`, `tbl_admin`.`admin_name` as `NAME` 
FROM `tbl_admin` INNER JOIN `tbl_user` ORDER BY `tbl_user`.`creation_date` DESC
```

Below is the result from my above query

```
ID | NAME  | ID | NAME
1  | John  | 1  | Bob
2  | Kevin | 1  | Bob
```

I want the result in the below format

```
ID | NAME  |
1  | John  |
1  | Bob   |
2  | Kevin |
```

I can write separate query for each table but in that case TABLE 1 result will load first and then TABLE 2 result but my goal is to get both TABLE results in a single query ORDER by ID or DATE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

```
(SELECT user_id AS Id
    , user_name AS Name
    FROM tbl_user)

UNION ALL

(SELECT admin_id
    , admin_name
    FROM tbl_admin)

ORDER BY Id;
```

Comment: The super query is redundant.

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks @Strawberry

Comment: ...as are the parentheses

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
      user_id as Id, user_name as Name
      tbl_user   

        UNION

    SELECT admin_id
        , admin_name
        FROM tbl_admin

    ORDER BY Id;
```

Use UNION